# What is the story of Indra going to Nara-Narayana Rishis for aid, as mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, indra, bhishma, nara-narayana

I know that Bhishma narrates this story to Duryodhana. Please give me the reference from the Mahabharata if you can. It would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This story in mentioned in [Mahabharata, Udyoga Parva, SECTION XLIX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05049.htm).

> "Bhishma continued, 'Having heard these words, Sakra went to the spot where those two were practising ascetic austerities, accompanied by all the celestials and having Vrihaspati at their head. At that time, the dwellers of heaven had been very much alarmed in consequence of a war raging between themselves and the Asuras. And Indra asked that illustrious couple to grant him a boon. Thus solicited, O best of the Bharata race, those two said,--Name thou the boon.--Upon this Sakra said unto them,--Give us your aid.--They then said unto Sakra,--We will do what thou wishest. And then it was with their aid that Sakra subsequently vanquished the Daityas and the Danavas.

Comment: Also add some background , context of the story.The story happened during Deva-Asura sangrama. Some gods including Indra went to Lord Brahma and meanwhile Nara-Narayana passed by from there , Brihaspati asked Brahma about them and Brahma told all about them  the purpose of these two i.e. to slay asuras and daityas.Then Indra and Brihaspati went to Nara-Narayana and asked for their help ,as a boon these two helped Indra in wining that battle. Nara-Narayana slayed many asuras and daityas in that battle.